# Click on drop-down list of QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, mouseevent

I currently have a `QComboBox` in a `QGraphicsScene` and I need it to detect clicks. To see if there is a widget in the clicked position, I use:

```
void BlockScene::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (itemAt(event->pos()) != m_widgetItem)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This works well for different widgets except for combo boxes where it only takes into account the original widget and not the drop-down list that appears after a first click.

To know if it came from the scene or not, I tested also by redefining `mousePressEvent` of the class `QComboBox` and same problem: It is called only when clicking on the initial widget.

Is there a way to get the drop-down list? To detect a click on it? Ideas?

Comment: A ComboBox uses the signal currentIndexChanged and not a mouse press event.

Comment: I agree but in my QGraphicsScene, I need to use it when the click is outside the combo box, including the drop-down list.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're after an onBlur event but Qt doesn't have one. The closest would be the activated signal but it doesn't say in the docs whether it sends the signal for leaving the widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom widget for the view of the combo, or for its completer.
For example, in a subclass of QComboBox, if you need a completer, try this code. MyListView is a subclass of QListView. On that, you can reimplement the mousePressEvent method

```
    completer()->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
    MyListView *comboView = new MyListView();
    completer()->setPopup(comboView);
```

if you don't need the completer, do the setView directly on the combobox.

```
MyListView *comboView = new MyListView();
setView(comboView);
```